How do I place the error bars with the right treatment?
As you can see on the picture, the error bars are displaced, and I want to fix that, but don't know how
# Assuming your data frame is named VC_out
library(agricolae)

# Check the structure of your data frame
#str(VC_out)

# Calculate means and standard errors for each treatment group
means <- aggregate(Rooting_index ~ Treatment, data = VC, FUN = mean)
standard_errors <- aggregate(Rooting_index ~ Treatment, data = VC, FUN = function(x) sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)))

# Run LSD test
lsd.cc <- LSD.test(VC_out, "Treatment")

# Plot results
bar.group(lsd.cc$groups, ylim = c(0, 5))

# Add error bars
for (i in 1:nrow(means)) {
  arrows(i, means$Rooting_index[i] - standard_errors$Rooting_index[i], 
         i, means$Rooting_index[i] + standard_errors$Rooting_index[i], 
         angle = 90, code = 3, length = 0.05)


}

# Add title and axis labels
title(main = "Rooting Index by Treatment", xlab = "Treatment", ylab = "Rooting Index")



The error bars are displaced and I would like to correct that, but I don't know how

Welcome to SO. What's "VC_out"? We can't see the image you refer to in your post because you used a link to the image instead of the image. You found a way to add a link, which is right next to the button to insert an image. Help others to help you. Edit your question to meet these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
